# weird jquery and IE issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I found a weird problem with jQuery and IE and I was wondering if there is a fix or a work around. Basically, when the page initially loads, or if it is accessed directly from the url (eg. you copy paste the url and go to it), The page gives jQuery errors in IE (all other browsers are fine).

However, on the same page, if you refresh the page, everything runs and loads just fine. Has anybody encounter such problem?

Comment: What is the jQuery code that's throwing the error?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact code because IE does not have the best error reporting. The actual error message points to a line/col in the actual jQuery file, not my jQuery calls.

Comment: No errors in other browsers?  Can you strip down your page to try and determine which jQuery call is leading to the error?

Comment: I figured it out:
apparently this is caused if you have the content-type meta tag:

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
after loading the jQuery. To fix, you just have to make sure to put that line before loading your jQuery. Very weird though, I would expect something like this to error on all browsers, not only IE.

Comment: @kennypu Well, we all know how bad IE is. Very disobedient.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: apparently this is caused if you have the content-type meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

after loading the jQuery. To fix, you just have to make sure to put that line before loading your jQuery. Very weird though, I would expect something like this to error on all browsers, not only IE.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a cache error. Usually it happens when you try to reference DOM objects that aren't loaded yet.

Make sure you wrap your jquery in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

That way the DOM will be ready before you start messing with it.